# Removing apacheinstallation from multiple package-managements

Tags: php, apache, homebrew, macports

I am pretty new at this Mac OS thingy and I tried installing PHP54 on it. I know, there is a ton of tutorials out there and trust me, I have spend hours online reading. The problem is I am a newbie and I became impatient and just started installing from Brew, Port and compiling my own.

I really just want to start over, but I would like not to reinstall the OS and I really want to understand how to install into different folder, if I for example want different versions of PHP. (I saw that someone had that in a video tutorial, but he did not tell how to do it)

So the following is my questions to you experts:

1. How to remove all files from a HomeBrew-install (I think I removed some manually, so that the auto-remover don't work anymore)
2. How to remove all files from a MacPort-install (same as above)
3. How to remove the default PHP installation (I've managed to update it, but I don't think it was made correctly)
4. How to install a new version of PHP 5.3 along with 5.4 and 5.5
5. Installing MySQL and PhpMyAdmin so that it works with my PHP (I could not connect to the MySQL server the last time I installed it)

I don't think I have made any changes to the Apache-server (hopefully not)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose to do a reinstall of my OSX